# XAMPP MySQL will not start

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hey so I'm fairly new to php and XAMPP etc. And I want to create a login system but that requires me to haveing a MySQL but when starting I get this error I looked it up and foudn I had to delete ibdata1 but it keeps coming back anyone knows how to fix this?

```
7:18:52  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
7:18:53  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
7:18:56  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
7:18:56  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:18:56  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:18:56  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:18:56  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:18:56  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:18:56  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
7:18:56  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Did you see the port using of your xampp? Some reasons why the xampp is not running is, the port of your xampp is used by another application for example (Wamp Server).

Comment: If i recall correctly, Skype uses the same default port, if you're running skype simultaneously try changing the skype default port or the ports in your xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL uses 3306 as it’s default port.

As Apache port, we also can NOT change the MySQL port through the XAMPP Control Panel, to change it we have to edit MySQL configuration file.

To edit the configuration file, open my.ini file located in the XAMPP/mysql/bin/ directory, find words that contain number 3306, eq: port = 3306, then replace it with your own, such as 3307.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your MySQL connection port in xampp config file. Its default port 3306 and check this port on your process. Close all process in this port or change mysql connection port in your xampp config file.